# How should I install gitlab-runners on Linux?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am on Linux, and here are the system details:
Linux maltserver 5.4.0-47-generic #51~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Sep 5 14:35:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I get the following error trying to install a gitlab-runner:

```
tania@maltserver:~$ helm install --namespace gitlab gitlab-runner -f values.yaml  gitlab/gitlab-runner
Error: failed to download "gitlab/gitlab-runner" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
tania@maltserver:~$ helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. â Happy Helming!â
tania@maltserver:~$ helm install --namespace gitlab gitlab-runner -f values.yaml  gitlab/gitlab-runner
Error: failed to download "gitlab/gitlab-runner" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

Also tried the following:

```
tania@maltserver:~$ helm search hub gitlab/gitlab-runner
URL                                                     CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/gitlab/gitlab-runner         0.21.0-rc1      13.4.0-rc1      GitLab Runner
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/camptocamp/gitlab-ru...      0.12.6          12.6.0          GitLab Runner
tania@maltserver:~$ helm install --namespace gitlab gitlab-runner -f values.yaml https://hub.helm.sh/charts/gitlab/gitlab-runner
Error: file '/home/tania/.cache/helm/repository/gitlab-runner' does not appear to be a gzipped archive; got 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
```

Any help with successful gitlab-runner installation will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working now, I had to do:

```
tania@maltserver:~$ helm repo add https://charts.gitlab.io
tania@maltserver:~$ helm install --namespace gitlab gitlab-runner -f values.yaml  gitlab/gitlab-runner
NAME: gitlab-runner
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Sep 15 13:19:53 2020
NAMESPACE: gitlab
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
Your GitLab Runner should now be registered against the GitLab instance reachable at: "https://gitlab.com/"
```

Resource:

```
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html
```